# Trouble with cookies

Tags: logic, argumentation

```
Matter cannot be created.
Cookies are matter.
So cookies cannot be created.
```

I know this seems absurd but I'm using this to make an important point about arguments.

The argument appears to be valid and each premise appears to be true so it would appear to be sound.

But the conclusion is obviously false.

So what's the specific issue that we might have missed had the content of this argument been more abstract?

Comment: This is more of a wordplay than philosophy, you are making a trivial [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) on "created". In the first sentence it means "created out of nothing", and with that the conclusion is also true. And if it meant "created from a different kind of  matter" then the premise is false.

Comment: If the argument is valid and the conclusion is false, then at least one of the premises must be false.

Comment: But are you sure that the conclusion is true ?

Comment: good spot, thanks @Conifold you beat this reader to it

Answer (score 4):

Cookies are not matter.  Cookies are made up of matter.  They are a structured form of matter.

The logic you provided does not prohibit the existence of matter that existed before the epoch where these three statements hold true.

The initial creation of all matter at the beginning of the universe is a complex thing.  It is not clear whether "Matter cannot be created" applies to the first 10^-43 seconds of the universe.  After that point, it seems rather robust.

Answer (score 1):

- Nothing is better than eternal happiness.
- A ham sandwich is better than nothing.
- ∴ A ham sandwich is better than eternal happiness.

This is an example of the Four Terms fallacy of syllogistic logic, in which a single word — 'nothing' in this case — is used in two different senses to produce an erroneous result.

You've made this error above. 'Matter' in the first premise refers to physical material in its most basic form, but 'matter' in the second premise points at a *form* that is *constructed* of matter, not at matter itself. Forms can be created and destroyed, but creating or destroying a form means the transformation of its constituent matter into some different form, not the outright destruction of that matter.

Did you think that when you eat a cookie you are using your teeth to destroy the component atoms of that cookie? No, you're simply breaking chemical bonds so that the 'matter' of the cookie can be more easily extracted and combined with the physical matter of your organism. If you destroyed the matter of everything you tried to eat, you'd starve to death.